# inconclusive results in jmeter during load testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am trying to understand the working of jmeter for load testing for aws cloudsearch. I ran 1500 threads I get average load time as 1500 ms but when I run 15 threads i get 10ms as my average load time. Shouldn't both be equal? Can someone please explain this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't both be equal?

Not at all!

In fact, that's the point. By adding more users (an extra 1485, in your case), you're making the server work harder. It has more requests to process, each of which take Memory, CPU, Threads in various queues, etc. One of these resources is a **bottleneck**, meaning that it's stopping your server from running as efficiently as you'd like. For instance, if your CPU is stuck at 100%, adding more memory won't do anything.

---

There are two things that you can (need to?) do next:

1) Find where the bottleneck occurs- does it happen at 1000 users? 500 users?

2) Find the bottleneck, fix it, and run more users.

The key to either of these is **monitoring**. You need to know what's going on on your server before you can tell what's going wrong on it.

Comment: i was looking at the throughput. at 15 threads the throughput is around 1500 /s and at 1500 threads the throughput is 100/s. More throughput means more requests so at 15 threads threads the server should be processing more requests and the response time should go down right...

Comment: When a server gets overloaded, it gets less efficient. It can't process requests as easily. When you add a few more threads (ie, 20), then yes, throughput should go up. Eventually though, the server will get stuck. Maybe it fills up memory, so it spends time swapping instead of processing your requests. Throughput drops and response times will increase.

At no point should adding threads decrease response times.